# Regex: Search a digit from a string and exclude digit(can be integer/float) which is leading by 'N'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to exclude digit which is leading by N. For that, I used reverse tracking and below is regex i am using to exclude N10.5 from expression.

```
expression = "N10.5*33+31"
variable_refs = re.compile(r'\b(?<!N)([0-9])+(\.)?(\d+)?')
exp_template = re.sub(variable_refs, r'{key_\1}', expression)
print(exp_template)
```

output would be:
(key_33,key_31)

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: This regex not working properly.

Comment: Isn't your expected output `N10.5*{key_33}+{key_31}` as you don't want to match a number preceded by `N`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?<![N\d.])(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QlygYN/1)

`(?<![N\d.])` is negative look-behind assertion that **fails** the match if previous character is `N` or digit or dot.

Comment: I tried variable_refs = re.compile(r'\b((?<![N\d.])(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)')

Comment: You don't need `\b` also with this approach